# MockK capturing a suspend lambda / coroutine

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, kotlin-coroutines, suspend, mockk

I am trying to capture a suspend lambda / coroutine and invoke it, but the mocking call just hangs.

```
@Test
fun test() = coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    coEvery { db.withTransaction(captureCoroutine<suspend () -> Unit>()) } answers {
        coroutine<suspend () -> Unit>().coInvoke()
    }
}
```

Any hints or tips if I'm doing something wrong or is this just impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `coAnswers`:

```
@Test
fun test() = coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    coEvery { 
       db.withTransaction(captureCoroutine<suspend () -> Unit>())
    } coAnswers {
       coroutine<suspend () -> Unit>().coInvoke()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I found working is adding this function:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    mockkStatic("androidx.room.RoomDatabaseKt")
    coEvery { mockDatabase.withTransaction(captureCoroutine<suspend () -> Unit>()) } coAnswers {
        coroutine<suspend () -> Unit>().captured.invoke()
    }
}
```

Key thing was mocking `androidx.room.RoomDatabaseKt`. `coEvery` has to be inside the `setup` function, adding it when database mock is initialized also causes test to hang.